# I am tyring to import SQL file with command line

Tags: mysql, database, ssh

I am trying to import SQL file but it's not working, I have done this so many time importing database from one server to another

```
mysql –u [username] –p [database] < [file_name].sql
```

For some reason SQL file is empty after running the command also I am not getting any errors.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You are sure you use `<` not `>`? With the command in your question the sal file will not change

Comment: no i am using the command as i wrote before.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `-p` option you have to insert even the password, so:

```
mysql –u [username] –p [password] [database] < [file_name].sql
```